# Duplicate values with multiple joins in query

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to obtain comments made on a specific profile, but as soon as more than one person with a different relation (relation_id) to the profile has commented, I get duplicate, triplicate and so forth results.

Tables involved are as follows:

**Users** -
user_id
user_first_name
user_last_name
user_image path

**Profile comments** -
comment_id
profile_id
user_id
comment_body
comment_date

**Profile_user_relation** -
user_id
profile_id
relation_id

**Relation_types** -
relation_id 
relation_name

My query is as follows:

```
    SELECT profile_comments.*, 
        relation_types.relation_name, 
        users.user_first_name, 
        users.user_image_path 
    FROM profile_comments 
    LEFT JOIN profile_user_relation ON profile_comments.profile_id = profile_user_relation.profile_id 
    LEFT JOIN relation_types ON relation_types.relation_id = profile_user_relation.relation_id 
    LEFT JOIN users ON profile_comments.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE profile_comments.profile_id = :profileId
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test it out, but I think it should work, or at least to get you a little bit closer.

```
SELECT 
        C.*, 
        RT.relation_name, 
        U.user_first_name, 
        U.user_image_path 
FROM profile_comments      AS C 
JOIN users                 AS U  USING(user_id) 
JOIN profile_user_relation AS UR USING(user_id, profile_id) 
JOIN relation_types        AS RT USING(relation_id)


WHERE C.profile_id = :profileId
```

Hope that will be a bit helpful.

Comment: That is perfect, works right out of the box - Thank you! I will have to look into the use of USING :)